Downgrade MariaDB from 10.11.8 to 10.11.6?
After upgrading MariaDB to 10.11.8, we're experiencing error 1034 when adding or modifying indexes, which is a show stopper for us. I can reliably reproduce the errors on a new table, and the same operations worked just fine with the version we had before.
I think the old version was 10.11.6 but possibly 10.11.5.
Since these are point releases, would it be safe to just install the older version with all the data in place, or should I dump all data and restore? (The data is like 30 Gbyte spread across five databases and several tables, so dump + restore is a significant amount of work, which I'd prefer to not have to do.)
And how do I actually perform the downgrade? Can I just run the older version's MSI installer? Or is there anything else I need to do?
Platform is Windows Server 2019, 64 bit.
I have reported the bug here: https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-34500
I've been trying to find docs about downgrading, but most docs and StackExchange questions that I find refer to downgrading between "major" versions, which in MariaDB terms seem to include both e.g. 10.a.b -> 5.c.d and 10.11.x -> 10.4.x. I've been unable to find any docs regarding downgrading patch versions like what I've asked about, except it being mentioned in passing in this article: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/downgrading-between-major-versions-of-mariadb/ It mentions:

For minor versions, upgrade[SIC!] is supported to an earlier gamma/RC/GA version as we do not change the storage format after Alpha and very rarely during Beta (it has to be a very critical bug to require such a change). There are a few very rare cases when incompatible changes happen on a GA version, for example MariaDB 10.1.21 fixed a file format incompatibility bug that prevents a downgrade to earlier MariaDB 10.1 releases. After MariaDB 10.1.21 this has not happened in a GA release.

Based on that I tried installing 10.11.6 MSI on top of 10.11.8, but it just says there's a newer version installed and exits. I did download the 10.11.6 ZIP package and downgraded manually using folder diff, after shutting down the MariaDB service with innodb_fast_shutdown=0. So far so good and index creatin works again.
But I'd still like to know if this is the right thing to do in such situations.

Why are you changing the key column from int to varchar and back? I suspect MariaDb will need to add that to their test cases given it is probably non-existent now.

@GregAskew The CSV files come with a character prefix before the int value, and I want just the int value. I can convert on the fly in the load..., but that requires me to explicitly list the other 575 column names in the load SQL. Doable of course but not very nice. Even so, the bug shows up when I create index on some other unrelated int columns too, so fixing that data import doesn't fully solve the problem.

Wait. You are considering backing out a database upgrade and restoring 30 GB of data on multiple hosts because one column of a csv file that is imported has an unwanted character? All data imports should assume there will need to be some cleanup and transformation. This is next level wrong.

Downgrade like this is mostly fine, but Windows Installer (MSI) might not be happy with you replacing file it is managing  by your own. A cleaner version would be to save data directory, uninstall, install older version (also "create new service)", shutdown service, copy contents of saved data directory under directory of the new installation. Take care that files under datadir are are readable and writable by the service user "NT Service<service name>"

@GregAskew Looks like you didn't read properly. The error seems to occur on ANY index creation on that table, even if I work around the initial load.... There are obviously several ways to work around the problem of adding the primary key after import, including changes to the system that creates the file in the first place. But since indexing apparently fails IN GENERAL for that table, it wouldn't help. Will wait until the bug appears to be fix before upgrading again.

@VladislavVaintroub Thanks. Feel free to write that as an answer and I'll mark it a correct one.
